# Why doesn't urlencode and urldecode work?

Tags: php, url, get

here's the code i'm using:

```
$from=urldecode($_GET['from']);
$str =urldecode("%2B");
echo "$str<br>";
echo "$from<br>";
```

and here's part of the URL: `from=%2B995594262653`

why does this echo

```
+
 995594262653
```

? (note, there's a space in front of the number).
i am using `$str` to check if the function works at all. apparently, it works for a simple `%2B`. What could be an issue?

Comment: php decodes request automatically for you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is working, but you need to realise that PHP will [automatically urldecode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) the data it in puts in the $_GET array. You are doing it a *second* time and transforming the input even more.

When your script runs, `$_GET['from']` contains `+995594262653`

When you run that value through urldecode, the `+` gets transformed to a space.